# How to study the uniform convergence of $\sum\frac{n^{n+1}x^{n}e^{-nx}}{n!} ? x \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How to study the uniform convergence of $$\sum\frac{n^{n+1}x^{n}e^{-nx}}{n!} $$

I was thinking about the Weierstrass M-test, but if we consider as $$f_n(x) =\frac{n^{n+1}x^{n}e^{-nx}}{n!}$$.

The $f_n(x)$ takes max. value at $x=1$ so we consider $$M_n=\frac{n^{n+1}e^{-n}}{n!}$$ but $M_n$ does not converge.

Comment: I would use the change of variable $t:=xe^x$.

Comment: Please, show that you have worked on your exercise...

Comment: I have edited and changed a typing mistake

Comment: uniform convergence where?

Comment: for x >= 0. But probably i should closed the interval, for example $(0,a)$ idk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Study pointwise convergence first with the ratio test.